# ggplot2 geom_jitter jitters in y direction?

Tags: r, ggplot2, jitter, geom

I am very puzzled. When using ggplot2, many uses geom_jitter to add points to boxplots for instance. It is supposed to keep values on the Y-axis, at least as far as I know, and jitter values on the X-axis.

Using it today on two groups, 3 points per group, all the same values, I see it jitters values on the Y-axis.

```
library(ggplot2)

condition = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3))
fraction = c(rep(100, 3), rep(100, 3))
df = data.frame(condition, fraction)


ggplot(df, aes(condition, fraction))+
  geom_jitter(width = 0.2)+
  labs(title = "",
       x = "", y = "fraction")+
  ylim(95,105)+
  theme_classic()
```

Graph is below (sorry too new to post an image apparently, so that's a link):

[graph resulting from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9BGW.png)

Anyone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to SO.

`geom_jitter()` jitters both horizontally and vertically. To avoid vertical jitter, set `height = 0`.

```r
geom_jitter(height = 0, seed = 123)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Martin! I was not aware. Pretty dangerous and confusing to not have height = 0 by default, at least for me. Sorry I cannot +1, too new...

Comment: You're welcome. It certainly depends on the visualisation type. For a 2D scatterplot it's actually a plausible choice if we are interested in reducing [overplotting](https://www.displayr.com/what-is-overplotting/).

Comment: And a reasonable explanation! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

According to [documentation of geom_jitter](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_jitter.html) it can jitter in both dimensions. You can use `width` and `height` arguments to specify whether you want it to happen. Check out the example below

```
ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = mpg[1, ], aes(cty, hwy), color = "red") +
    geom_jitter(data = mpg[1, ], aes(cty, hwy), width = 0.5, height = 0.5, color = "blue") + 
    geom_jitter(data = mpg[1, ], aes(cty, hwy), width = 0.5, height = 0, color = "green")
```

Green dot always has same y-value as black dot (original) due to seting `height` to 0.

Comment: Thanks Dominik! Sorry I cannot +1, too new...